# Input string was not in a correct format? Prod Error

Tags: vb.net

My error message is as listed in the header "Input string was not in a correct format" however the stack trace is even more cryptic

`Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ParseDouble(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat) at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToDouble(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat)`

This is worse due to the fact that nowhere in the project does it use "ParseDouble". I believe that this has something to do with the objectfactorylibrary but can't pin anything down.

Has anyone seen something similar or point me in a general direction?

Edit:
Additional information, this is a production only issue with local, dev, and QA unable to reproduce the error in any environment but Production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack trace is referring to a method inside of the .NET Framework code, called `ParseDouble`. It does not exist in your code. This is why the entire namespace is included, so that you can tell where the method is defined. If it starts with `Microsoft` or `System`, it's not something you wrote.

You probably used the `CDbl` operator (it's that thing that looks like a function call to the uninitiated), and internally, the .NET Framework translated that to a call to the `Conversions.ToDouble` method, which internally calls the `Conversions.ParseDouble` method. These are implementation details that you should not have to be concerned with. Keep traveling up the stack trace until you find the last method called that is part of *your* code.

As far as why your code is throwing that error, it's almost impossible to say without seeing some code that reproduces it.

However, my psychic debugging powers tell me that you're probably trying to parse a string value into a number, and the method is failing because the string does not contain a valid number. Check the value of the string you're passing into the method and update your question. It's probably an issue of the language settings on your computer. Do you use a language where `,` (a comma) is the decimal separator rather than `.` (a period)?

Comment: agreed - Or a textbox has been left blank and then attempted to be cast to a number in your code.

Comment: I guess I should elaborate and I will edit as such but this is specifically a production issue with local, dev, and QA working fine. This leads me to believe it is not code but I have no where from there to go.

Comment: @user: No, it's still code that's responsible (and therefore fixable). The likely explanation is the one I presented: the system on which it is failing is using a different input locale than the test systems. Post the code that you *are* calling and someone can tell you how to modify it. The solution is going to involve specifying `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to the conversion method. But it might require calling a *different* conversion method other than `CDbl`.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to find the problem, buried deep in one of the loaded user controls. It was as simple as a try catch had been removed.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically telling you that you that it tried to convert a string to a number but couldn't as the string was not numeric (could have alpha or other characters in it).

The stack trace should point you towards the offending piece of code, if you're lucky you will have a line number. If this is a piece of code that usually works then take a look at the data (whatever it is).